# Execute long OS X command which has script as an argument with new lines via os.system

Tags: python, macos

I want to execute small warning message from bg proccess, it could be done in os x:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "SystemUIServer"
display dialog "message"
end
activate application (path to frontmost application as text)'
```

This command needs to have new lines, but I can't execute it in `os.system`, tried inserting `'\n', \n ...` but nothing works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
import subprocess
command = ['osascript', '-e', 'tell application "SystemUIServer"\ndisplay dialog "message"\nend\nactivate application (path to frontmost application as text)']
subprocess.check_call(command)
```